# kivy programs not working after ubuntu update from 19.10 to 20.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, kivy

I was working on Kivy on my ubuntu machine and it was working fine until I upgraded my ubuntu os from 19.10 to 20.04.after upgrading none of my kivy programs works.
I have checked both python and kivy are installed on my system.

I uninstalled kivy and installed it again but the problem was still there.
I am attaching the screenshot of the error I am getting while executing the kivy code on VS code.

[image]

another screenshot of my terminal with some information if needed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need the swrast driver installed for OpenGL rendering to work in headless mode. Typically,

```
sudo apt-get intall -y mesa-utils and libgl1-mesa-glx
```

will do it. But if you have proprietary video drivers installed, it may take some googling to find the answer.

thanks

Comment: I don't have any proprietary drivers installed. this command was executed and the problem is still the same. mesa-utils and libgl1-mesa-glx were installed individually as the command you have written gave me this error "E: Unable to locate package and".